# Implement sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync for syncing primary and secondary azure database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure

I want to implement sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync for each transaction to avoid the dataloss when failover happens from primary to secondary.

What is the best design ? Do we need to implement in the code level or Is there a  scheduler available in Azure which checks if there is an transaction. If there is a transaction, then automatically execute the SP.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sp_wait_for_database_copy_sync after transactions that you wish to be durable. You use it after transactions you want to force synchronization. However, forced synchronization impacts performance because it blocks the calling thread until all committed transactions are replicated. Remember on automatic failover groups you are replicating to another region and the lag time with respect to the RPO (recovery point objective) is 5 seconds for auto-failover groups.